# Android webview is not loading a URL

Tags: android

I am loading web page content with URL [link](http://www.google.com/maps/place?source=uds&q=Starbucks,%20200%20Uncle%20Petes%20Road,&cid=13546287177434883906)using web view, But i am facing an error:

> ERROR/Web Console(889): TypeError: Result of expression 'this.mb' [null] is not an object.

How can I resolve this problem. Please help me.

Comment: Can you please show some code where you create `this.mb` variable and where you use it.

Comment: I am not using 'this.mb' any where in my code. This Error from console only.

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to show map you need add:

```
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
```

EDIT: `webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);` helped.